# Notice: Undefined variable: version in Simple-LDAP-Login.php in line 54

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, ldap

I have installed WordPress `LDAP` plugin on my website. Now I am geeting this following Notice:

> Notice: Undefined variable: version in
>   /var/www/html/testinsite/wp-content/plugins/simple-ldap-login/Simple-LDAP-Login.php
>   on line 54

Please help me how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Simple-LDAP-Login.php

go to line 54 and change:

`$version` into `$this->version`

or modify this:

```
if( $this->get_setting('version') === false || $this->get_setting('version') != $version )
```

to your current plugin version (as a last resort until bug 50 is fixed)
`https://github.com/clifgriffin/simple-ldap-login/issues/50`

```
if( $this->get_setting('version') === false || $this->get_setting('version') != '1.6.0' )
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.I have tried this link https://wordpress.org/support/topic/fix-for-undefined-variable-version-in-simple-ldap-login-php/

Comment: And what error you get now? The error should have changed.

Comment: As a last resort you can put a constant there with your actual version which I think is `1.6.0` until a fix is merged on github: https://github.com/clifgriffin/simple-ldap-login/issues/50. The issue is still opened.